# How do I sign into the SQL Management area on Azure?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, azure

I have created a new SQL Server on Azure, and am trying to sign into their web based Management area.

What credentials do I need to provide?

I created the Database using the Quick Create wizard, and was never asked for a password.

I have tried my Windows Live username and password, this doesn't work. I have also tried the username specified in the connection string you get from Azure with and without the @foo you get afterwards, along with my Live ID password, neither of these work either.

I can't see anything in the portal providing a password.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the DB tab and select the DB server that was auto-created. Will have some random letters and numbers as a name.

On the dashboard of the server you should be able to reset the administrator password. On that page it should also give you the administrator login username.

Hope that helps,

Henry

edit: one other thing, you need to add your IP address as a management address. You can do this by going to the DB tab and clicking MANAGE at the bottom, should prompt you to add your IP to the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have no idea about the database created by the wizard, but if you go through the 'Custom Create' route on Azure, you have the opportunity to supply your own Username and Password, and these do work.